# c++ 17 filesystem(experimental/filesystem at Windows) remove all empty directories recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, filesystems, c++17

I'm trying to write a C++ script that uses the C++17 filesystem library to recursively remove all empty directories found at any given root directory(to make things clearer I'll use the cwd in this code sample).
So, say I have the following directory structure: `C:\Users\anrob\Pictures\SonyA100\2017\August\Week1\8-1-2017`
And I know that in this path `C:\Users\anrob\Pictures\SonyA100\2017\August\Week1\8-1-2017` is empty, `C:\Users\anrob\Pictures\SonyA100\2017\August\Week1` has nothing but the `8-1-2017` empty directory, and `C:\Users\anrob\Pictures\SonyA100\2017\August\` will also have nothing but the empty `Week1` directory once we remove `C:\Users\anrob\Pictures\SonyA100\2017\August\Week1\8-1-2017`.
Here is my current code(Note that I'm using Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24225.1 for x64):

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>  
int main() {
    std::experimental::filesystem::path top = 
std::experimental::filesystem::current_path(), 
    dir_path;
    for (auto& p: 
std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(top)) {
        dir_path = p.path();
        while (std::experimental::filesystem::is_directory(dir_path) && 
        std::experimental::filesystem::is_empty(dir_path)) {
            std::experimental::filesystem::remove(dir_path);
            dir_path = dir_path.parent_path();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this code, it only removes one empty directory(i.e., `C:\Users\anrob\Pictures\SonyA100\2017\August\Week1\8-1-2017`, and not all of the also soon-to-be empty directories.

Comment: Advice -- I hope you're testing the removal of directories on a file system you don't care about.  One bug, one typo, etc. and you could end up erasing a directory that's important.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's a controlled environment. I'm trying to do this just to learn more about the new C++17 filesystem library. Once it works, I'm going to implement it on a photo organizing and editing program. But thanks for the head's up, I appreciate it!

Comment: I would expect it's not a good idea to remove files/directories while you're iterating over them. Maybe try copying the paths of the empty directories to a vector, and then when you are done iterating, remove all of them.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I already tried that, but the problem is that some directories only become empty when I remove the empty directories inside them...

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to try one more time copying the paths to a vector of paths, as @BenjaminLindley suggested.
It didn't work, once again...
Then I decided to take another deep look at [the Filesystem library documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs).
After a thorough reading of the documentation, I realised I should be using the canonical paths and that I should iterate over this vector of canonical paths with a reverse iterator.
My script is now working like a charm, "recursively" removing all the empty directories as expected.
I think it's a good idea to share my solution here, since I really just couldn't find any clear answer to my earlier question.
I would really appreciate if the Stack Overflow community could upvote this answer and even this question, because I don't think I'm going to be the only person to ever stumble on that problem.
Lastly, here's my solution to the problem:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>  
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::experimental::filesystem::path top = std::experimental::filesystem::current_path();
    std::experimental::filesystem::path dir_path;
    std::vector<std::experimental::filesystem::path> directories;
    for (auto& p: std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(top)) {
        dir_path = p.path();
        if (std::experimental::filesystem::is_directory(dir_path)) {
            directories.push_back(std::experimental::filesystem::canonical(dir_path));
        }
    }
    for (std::vector<std::experimental::filesystem::path>::reverse_iterator rit = directories.rbegin(); rit != directories.rend(); ++rit) {
        if (std::experimental::filesystem::is_empty(*rit)) {
            std::experimental::filesystem::remove(*rit);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you push directory to vector if it is not empty?

Comment: A `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem` would make things way more readable.

Comment: @Artemy Vysotsky I push all the directories into the vector because after removing an empty directory inside one parent directory, this parent directory may also become empty. That's why I used a reverse iterator to check if the directories are empty and then remove them if so. I had to use a reverse iterator because of the way the reverse_directory_iterator function iterates over a given path.

Comment: @akim That's true! But this code is actually inside a header file and I don't think it's a good idea to do this inside a header file... But I'm still learning C++, so would you recommend using `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; ` inside a header file?

Comment: You can always do that in the function itself.  Besides, most of the calls in your code would be easily resolved by ADL.  Also, `dir_path` should be in the loop, and be a `const&`.  Yet, it is useless, you can use `p` directly.

Comment: @akim Thanks for your advice. I didn't know I could do that in the function itself. And you're right, using `dir_path = p.path()` is totally unnecessary in this situation.
As I said, I'm totally new to C++ and I didn't even know about the ADL, but I just read about it in the documentation. Thank you for your tips and advice again!